# How can I set File List with previous object?

Tags: javascript, http

The code below is made for creating an array of file objects with no duplicates, from a drag and drop situtation(the user drag some files here, some files there, organize the order, and finally upload the images):

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
var fileList = [];

fileInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    

    var fileInputArray = [...fileInput.files];
    
    fileList = fileInputArray.concat(fileList);

    fileList = Array.from(new Set(fileList.map(a => a.name))).map(name => {
        return fileList.find(a => a.name === name)
    });

    });

var fileCatcher = document.getElementById("file-catcher");

fileCatcher.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    let x = undefined;

    x = Object.assign({}, [...fileList]);
    fileInput.files = x;

    });
```

And my problem is in this line of the code:

```
fileInput.files = x;
```

As many of you already know, File List is ready only.

I tried so many variations, `for in`, `for of`, tried to hardcode a File List length with some great number(20 as an example), but all failed.

But I absolutely need to "hack this", because what I want to do is taking no duplicate images, from a drag and drop file situation, with some delete buttons as well.

I need to upload the files and the text with a single submit. It is no problem to when you upload as a batch, but with this "personalization" I've found myself lost.

I was trying, in some way, to replace the content of File List before uploading, but it is read only.

If I `preventDefault();` I have no clue how I'm gonna treat the data in my server. The whole server is configured to take all the info from one single `POST`

If I just had some way of writing a File List, the problem would be solved

Can someone help me? It is really frustrating seing all great work going to be useless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing a `XHR POST`, sending a `FormData` object